# Using Maven for Trunk based development

Tags: maven, anypoint-studio, trunk

I'm on a project that uses Mulesofts Anypoint studio for API development. Anypoint studio uses Maven to build its projects and handle versioning. Currently we are using a Git-flow branching model without release branches (feature/development/master) and the CI tool is Jenkins. We want to migrate to Azure-DevOps with Trunk-based branching.

The current git-flow CI set-up works as follows:

1. Merge feature with Dev
2. Jenkins triggers on Dev and builds a package with Maven
3. Jenkins deploys the package to D
4. Test your API on the D, if its good manually trigger Jenkins release pipeline
5. Jenkins will merge dev with master
6. Maven creates a release; creating a package (e.g. v0.1) and prepare the next development iteration (v0.2-SNAPSHOT) in master
7. Jenkins Deploys the package on A and P
8. Merge master back into Dev

So we have 2 separate pipelines here: dev and release. I'm hoping trunk-based development makes this process simpler by reducing it to one pipeline that is triggered by merges into master. But I don't know how to handle the versioning with Maven here.

This is what I have in mind for the Trunk-based (feature/master) pipeline:

1. Merge feature with Master
2. Azure pipelines triggers Maven release
3. **(!)** Maven takes the 0.1-SNAPSHOT version and creates a 0.1 release version and puts it..where? in a release branch?
4. Maven then creates the next working version 0.2-SNAPSHOT on the master branch
5. **(!)** this would trigger Azure pipelines again, creating a loop

Anyone have experience with Trunk Based development with Maven solve this? I would actually prefer to do it without a release branch because the released packages are already providing the release-branch functionality.

At first glance [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54050444/release-version-commit-in-trunk-based-development) seemingly solves my issue, but it just ignores the issue by going around it and just using a hash.

Comment: What exactly do you want to know about versioning?

Comment: Hey JF Meier, I've elaborated my answer. I hope you can see the issue I'm running into.

Comment: To further clarify, Maven Release is a specific plugin that takes care of versioning.
http://maven.apache.org/maven-release/maven-release-plugin/examples/prepare-release.html

Comment: I answered this couple of times, see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60856993/886697 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/48269714/886697